# ПУСТАЯ ошибка в Unity 2020.3.1f

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-editor

При запуске Unity возникает пустая ошибка из-за которой нельзя забилдить игру. Удаляла проект и закачивала его заново, переустанавливала эту версию Unity и ничего не помогло. Недавно полностью комп сносила поэтому это бесполезно было бы. До этого приложение было рабочим.
[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Возможные проблемы:

1. Проблемы с Windows, скорее всего стоит неправильное обновление Windows.
2. Не корректно работает .NET Framework или .NET Standard.

Возможное решение без установок:
Поменять .NET и перезапустить Unity.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]